# Firebase Ad Performance events not showing

Tags: android, firebase, admob, ads, firebase-analytics

I'm using Firebase Mobile Ad Performance feature that is in beta now (it is version 10.2.3).
I added the SDK and was able to see using Firebase DebugView that events like `ad_impression` and `ad_click` are collecting. However they are not showing on Ad Performance tile on Analytics tab - it shows all zeros.

Do you know why it's happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was related to time or number of users (not sure which one actually). When I released the app and waited for about two days events started showing.